# (q/kdb+) Use columns as input for a function row by row and append result into the table

Tags: kdb

I have the functions:

```
lsfit:{(enlist y) lsq x xexp/: til 1+z};
interp:{[xn;x;y]sum (1;xn)*flip lsfit[x;y;1]};
```

and the table

```
table:([] amount:500 730 1250;xRng:(0 1;0 1;1 2);yRng:(5 7f; 5 7f; 7 10f));table

amount  xRng    yRng
500     0 1     5 7f
730     0 1     5 7f
1250    1 2     7 10f
```

How can I apply `interp` to return a column "result" and append it to the table like below?

```
amount  xRng    yRng    result
500     0 1     5 7f    6
730     0 1     5 7f    6.46
1250    1 2     7 10f   7.75
```

I was trying something like

```
interp[first table[`amount]%1000;first table[`xRng];first table[`yRng]]
```

which works fine for the first row, but not sure how to extent it for the whole table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to apply your function to all the rows:

```
update result:interp'[amount%1000;xRng;yRng] from table
```

Comment: Thanks vm, What is the deal with the ' (tick)? I tried before without it, which did not work.

Comment: The '(tick) is each-both, this will allow you to carry out the operation on each row of your table.  More infromation can be found here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both